# SimpleXML storing attributes in an array

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml, openweathermap

My code is sort of working but I'm not getting the output which I want, I literally just want the output "Gentle Breeze" but instead I am getting "SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Gentle Breeze )"

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <title>Open Weather API</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=16&appid=Key";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    foreach($xml->forecast->time as $times)
    {
        $windspeed[] = $times->windSpeed["name"];
    }

    print_r($windspeed[0])
?>
</body>
```

I have tried using echo instead of print_r but all that gets outputted is "Array"

Here is an example of the XML I am pulling from the API:

```
<time day="2016-08-19">
  <symbol number="500" name="light rain" var="10d"/>
  <precipitation value="2.97" type="rain"/>
  <windDirection deg="188" code="S" name="South"/>
  <windSpeed mps="5.28" name="Gentle Breeze"/>
  <temperature day="22.58" min="17.06" max="22.58" night="18.39" eve="18.61" morn="17.06"/>
  <pressure unit="hPa" value="1012.32"/>
  <humidity value="72" unit="%"/>
  <clouds value="overcast clouds" all="92" unit="%"/>
</time>
```

I need to store it in an array so I can call it later on in my code, I'm just outputting the results as a test to see what is stored in the array and I just want it to store "Gentle Breeze" not "SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Gentle Breeze )"

Comment: Looks like a multidimensional array, try `echo $windspeed[0][0]`

Comment: I have tried that and it didnt seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple cast to string should achieve what you want:

```
foreach($xml->forecast->time as $times)
{
    $windspeed[] = (string) $times->windSpeed["name"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try doing this instead:

```
$windspeed[] = $times->windSpeed->name;
```

or

```
var_dump ($times->windSpeed->name);
```

Comment: that isnt storing it in an array?

Comment: I updated my answer, but was just giving you an example to see if that attribute resolves to type string

Comment: I need to use $windspeed[] = $times->windSpeed["name"]; if i just type echo $xml->forecast->time->windSpeed["name"]; I get the output "Gentle Breeze" so i dont understand why the array is storing something different

Comment: @LukeRayner: That’s because outputting via echo automatically triggers the conversion into a string value. If you want to get a string value for use in other contexts, that don’t _require_ a string value and therefor do not automatically convert it, you need to cast it to a string explicitly, see my answer.